# Why can't I connect OBS to my transcoding server?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, obs

I'm trying to write a server that will take incoming RTMP video and transcode to HLS for live streaming. I'm using ffmpeg on my server for the transcoding. Here is the ffmpeg command I am running:

`ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/test -c:v libx264 -x264opts keyint=120:no-scenecut -s 1280x720 -r 60 -b:v 5M -profile:v main -preset veryfast -c:a libfdk_aac -sws_flags bilinear -hls_list_size 6 output.m3u8`

I'm confident that this is the correct usage of ffmpeg for transcoding because I read about it [here](https://blog.twitch.tv/live-video-transmuxing-transcoding-ffmpeg-vs-twitchtranscoder-part-i-489c1c125f28).

When I run my server and try to connect to it using OBS (Open Broadcaster Software) I get an error from OBS saying failed to connect to server. I get this error from ffmpeg:

RTMP_Connect0, failed to connect socket. 111 (Connection refused)
rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/test: Unknown error occurred

Here is a capture of the packets sent between the applications.

[image: wireshark capture of OBS connecting to my server]

Here are the OBS setting I'm using to stream to my server:
[image: OBS Streaming Settings]

Edit: When I remove `/test` from the url in my ffmpeg command and in the OBS settings window I get this:
[image: ffmpeg error 2]

Comment: You are using both ffmpeg and abs as rtmp clients. What are you using as the rtmp server? (RTMP requires a 'reflector' for the broadcaster client and receiver client to connect to)

Comment: @szatmary I see. So the reflector should be listening for connections from OBS and from my transcode server?

Comment: Yes. There are may examples available doing just this. search for 'nginx+rtmp'